# function not filling empty vector in R

Tags: r

I'm  to get the vector simualted_results to take values returned by "simulation," which produced a vector of varying length depending on the iteration.

Initially I have this code which works, but is very slow:

```
simulated_results<-NULL
while(as.numeric(Sys.time())-start<duration){
  simulated_results <- cbind(simulated_results,simulation(J,4* (length(J)^2),0.0007,duration,start))

 }
```

But its very slow so I modified it:

```
start<-as.numeric(Sys.time())
duration<-10
simulated_results<-NULL
simulated_results <- cbind(simulated_results,
                       replicate(n=10000,expr=(while(as.numeric(Sys.time())-start<duration)
                         {simulation(J,4*(length(J)^2),0.0007,duration,start)})))
```

Now with the new code, my problem is that despite everything running, I cant get the results of simulation to be passed to simualted_results, instead simualted_results jsut takes on a column vector of NULL values
I get no error messages

I would greatly appreciate any help!!

for reference the simulation code is:

```
iter<-as.numeric(Sys.getenv("PBS_ARRAY_INDEX"))

if(iter <= 40){J<-1:500
}else if(iter <= 80){J<-1:1500
}else if(iter <= 120){J<-1:2500
}else if(iter <= 160){J<-1:5000}

set.seed(iter)
simulation <- function(J,gens,v=0.1,duration,start){

  species_richness <- function(J){
    a <- table(J)
    return(NROW(a))
  }

  start<-as.numeric(Sys.time())

  species_richness_output <- rep(NA,gens)
  for(rep in 1:gens){

    if (as.numeric(Sys.time())-start<duration){

      index1 <- sample(1:length(J),1)

      if(runif(1,0,1) < v){
        J[index1] <- (rep+100)
      } 
      else{
        index2 <- sample(1:length(J),1)
        while(index1==index2) {
          index2 <- sample(1:length(J),1)
        }
        J[index1] <- J[index2]
      }
      species_richness_output[rep] <- species_richness(J)} else break
  }

  species_abundance <- function(J){
    a <- table(J)
    return(a)
  }

  abuntable <- species_abundance(J)

  octaves <- function(abuntable)
  {
    oct<-rep(0,floor(log2(length(J))+1))

    for(i in 1:length(abuntable)){
      oct2 <- floor(log2(abuntable[i])+1)
      oct[oct2] <- oct[oct2]+1
    }

    return(oct)
  }   

  octaves(abuntable)
}
```

Comment: There are a number of problems here.. Your code is jumbled and unclear, we don't have the function 'simulation()' and even if we did, it looks like you're using the combination cbind()..replicate()..simulation() very incorrectly..  Even your paragraph describing your problem is incoherent.  You're not likely to get any help without clearly describing your data and how you want to manipulate it.

Comment: You can also use your old code, and preallocate the data structures you need for your results. The slowness comes from the constant reallocation of memory as your object grows.

Comment: I think we'll need to see `simulation()` to know how to help you.  Is `J` in the global environment?

Comment: Okay I'll put the rest of the code up but that's not where the problem is, the problem is in the combination of cbind and replicate

Comment: OK, I ran `simulation` and it returns a numeric vector.  So you you have to use a list to combine your answers.  I'll update my answer below.  Also, you don't need `start` as an argument, it's fixed w/i the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Nathan G, but something did catch my attention:  You are trying to `cbind` two things that cannot be bound together, since they have different dimensions.  We don't know what kind of data type your `simulation` function returns, but it clearly is not `NULL`.  Consider this:

```
df1 <- NULL
df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20)
cbind(df1, df2)
cbind(df2, df1)
```

Both `cbind` statements give errors.  Do you get an error? If this is what's going on, you should initialize `simulated_results` not as `NULL` but as an empty version of whatever the function `simulation` returns.

**EDIT**

```
iter = 10
set.seed(iter)
J <- 1:1500
# critical to preallocate the list size for speed
res <- vector("list", iter)
for (i in 1: iter) {
    res[[i]] <- simulation(J,4* (length(J)^2),0.0007,duration = 10,start)
}
str(res)
res[[1]]
```

Now I don't think I'm using this quite the way you ultimately intend, but perhaps this will give you enough to get to what you actually want.

Comment: No I don't get an error, it's just that the simulated results vector doesn't take the output from the replicated simulation functionl.
the simulation function outputs a vector of varying length, and it runs fine, the problem is that the combination of cbind and replicate  isnt filling the NULL vector

Comment: `simulation` "outputs a vector of varying length"  Assuming this is a numeric or integer vector, if the length varies, you will never be able to `cbind` it to anything.  You could concatenate it to the existing results: `simulated_results <- c()` and then change `cbind` to just `c` but this gives you one long vector with all your output. If that is not what you want, you may need to use a `list` which can have elements of varying length.  See `?list`.

Comment: @user1987097 Were you able to get it to work the way you wanted?